# getting Facebook friends list from a php server

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get facebook friends Id of a specific facebook user. how can i do this?

in detail : I have a server, and form a mobile I'll send a facebook id of a user to that server. accoding to that facebook id I want to get facebook ids of friends of that user. (this should do from server) please any one guide me to do that.

answer =  for this we should have access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like facebook wouldn't like that :)
You could scan profile.php?id=&sk=friends and parse the output for the ids.
But I'm sure the habe some fancy Ajax running giving you an easier method.

Have you checked their API? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/FriendList/
But you need permissions for that.

Comment: I tried to that using graph API but it need users access token which i don't have. :(

Comment: And also I need to get list of friends not the friendlists ( i don't think this makes any different)